# How to get the output shape of a layer in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have the following code in Keras (Basically I am modifying this code for my use) and I get this error:

'ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv3d_3 to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (10, 4096)'

Code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv3D
from keras.layers.convolutional_recurrent import ConvLSTM2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
from keras import layers

# We create a layer which take as input movies of shape
# (n_frames, width, height, channels) and returns a movie
# of identical shape.

model = Sequential()
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                   input_shape=(None, 64, 64, 1),
                   padding='same', return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                   padding='same', return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                   padding='same', return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                   padding='same', return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv3D(filters=1, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
               activation='sigmoid',
               padding='same', data_format='channels_last'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adadelta')
```

the data I feed is in the following format: [1, 10, 64, 64, 1].
So I would like to know where I am wrong and also how to see the output_shape of each layer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can get the output shape of a layer by [`layer.output_shape`](https://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/).

```
for layer in model.layers:
    print(layer.output_shape)
```

Gives you:

```
(None, None, 64, 64, 40)
(None, None, 64, 64, 40)
(None, None, 64, 64, 40)
(None, None, 64, 64, 40)
(None, None, 64, 64, 40)
(None, None, 64, 64, 40)
(None, None, 64, 64, 40)
(None, None, 64, 64, 40)
(None, None, 64, 64, 1)
```

Alternatively you can pretty print the model using [`model.summary`](https://keras.io/models/about-keras-models/):

```
model.summary()
```

Gives you the details about the number of parameters and output shapes of each layer and an overall model structure in a pretty format:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv_lst_m2d_1 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, None, 64, 64, 40)  59200     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, None, 64, 64, 40)  160       
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_2 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, None, 64, 64, 40)  115360    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, None, 64, 64, 40)  160       
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_3 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, None, 64, 64, 40)  115360    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, None, 64, 64, 40)  160       
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_4 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, None, 64, 64, 40)  115360    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (Batch (None, None, 64, 64, 40)  160       
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_1 (Conv3D)            (None, None, 64, 64, 1)   1081      
=================================================================
Total params: 407,001
Trainable params: 406,681
Non-trainable params: 320
_________________________________________________________________
```

If you want to access information about a specific layer only, you can use `name` argument when constructing that layer and then call like this:

```
...
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(..., name='conv3d_0'))
...

model.get_layer('conv3d_0')
```

---

**EDIT:** For reference sake it will always be same as `layer.output_shape` and please don't actually use Lambda or custom layers for this. But you can use [`Lambda`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda) layer to echo the shape of a passing tensor.

```
...
def print_tensor_shape(x):
    print(x.shape)
    return x
model.add(Lambda(print_tensor_shape))
...
```

Or write a custom layer and print the shape of the tensor on `call()`.

```
class echo_layer(Layer):
...
    def call(self, x):
        print(x.shape)
        return x
...

model.add(echo_layer())
```

Comment: I know the 'model.summary()" and 'layer.output_shape', actually I meant after feeding the data I would like to see the output shape, in other words, I do not know why I get the mentioned error: 'ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv3d_3 to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (10, 4096)'

Comment: I have tried to run the model with your inputs. `model.fit(np.ones((1, 10, 64, 64, 1)), np.ones((1, 1, 64, 64, 1)))` worked for me. What does your `y` look like?

Comment: my 'y' shape is the same as 'x' shape. Basically, I am using "Moving mnist" dataset where each sequence is 20 frames and I am trying to predict the second 10 frames based on the first 10 frames.

Comment: @MaryamRahmaniMoghaddam Can you check the shape of your `y` again, I can't reproduce the error while fitting `x.shape = y.shape = (1, 10, 64, 64, 1)`. By looking at the error (10, 4096). It looks like your inputs or `y` is somehow flattened. If it is your `y` you may need to reshape or change the output shape of your model.

Comment: you are right. my 'y' was not in the right format. but now I am getting this error "AttributeError: 'ProgbarLogger' object has no attribute 'log_values'". do you also get this error?

Comment: @MaryamRahmaniMoghaddam no I don't but seems like errors related to progress bar is usually something to do with train/test splits and validation arguments on fit (which I didn't give). Check [this github thread](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3657) for similar errors.

Comment: When I try this I get `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'output_shape'`. e.g.   after running  `top = Concatenate()([layer1, layer2])
    print(top.output_shape)`   (using Keras 2.2)

Comment: @umotto what is the meaning of Param # ?

Comment: @Vincent **Param #** column represents the weights and other adjustable (during the training with backprop) parameters for that layer. For example, number of parameters in a simple dense layer would be calculated as `params = weights = output_size * (input_size + 1)` where +1 is the bias. `ConvLSTM2D` layers are a bit more complicated to calculate. Also sometimes these parameters are static or in this case (`BatchNormalization` layers) not updated with the backprop training but with statistical methods using variance and mean, thus the 320 non-trainable params below.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the output shape with 'output.shape[1:]' command. It will get the shape of output layer and can be used for other purposes.