# How to feed ensemble model same input data as its sub models?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to create an ensemble model that gets the same input as the sub models.

```py
models = list()
nb_models = 3

#load all sub models
for i in range(nb_models):
    model_tmp = load_model("lstm_model"+str(i+1)+".h5")
    model_tmp.name = "model_"+str(i+1)
    models.append(model_tmp)

def create_ensemble(models,model_input):

    # take-in all outputs fro all models
    outModels = [model(model_input) for model in models]

    # calculate average of all results
    outAvg = layers.average(outModels)

    # merge into one model

    modelMerge = Model(inputs=model_input,outputs=outAvg,name='ensemble')

    return modelMerge

model_input = Input(shape=models[0].input_shape[1:])
modelEns = create_ensemble(models,model_input)
```

When I load my ensemble model and feed it same data as I did for seperate sub models, I got the following error.

> You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'lstm_2_input' with dtype float and shape [1,1,1] [[{{node lstm_2_input}}]]

For the three sub models they have:

```py
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (1, 1)                    12        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (1, 1)                    2         
=================================================================
```

and for the ensemble model:

```py
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 1, 1)         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
model_1 (Sequential)            multiple             14          input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
model_2 (Sequential)            multiple             14          input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
model_3 (Sequential)            multiple             14          input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
average_1 (Average)             (None, 1)            0           model_1[1][0]                    
                                                                 model_2[1][0]                    
                                                                 model_3[1][0]                    
==================================================================================================
```

```py
test_reshaped.shape() 
(28, 1, 1)
```

Comment: can you add the summary of each model, something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/49527269/5094841 and the shape of your data

Comment: I edited the question with more details

Answer (score 0):

See this example taken from [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/keras-functional-api-deep-learning/)

```
# Multiple Inputs
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.merge import concatenate
```

**First input model**

```
visible1 = Input(shape=(64,64,1))
conv11 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(visible1)
pool11 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv11)
conv12 = Conv2D(16, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(pool11)
pool12 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv12)
flat1 = Flatten()(pool12)
```

**Second input model**

```
visible2 = Input(shape=(32,32,3))
conv21 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(visible2)
pool21 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv21)
conv22 = Conv2D(16, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(pool21)
pool22 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv22)
flat2 = Flatten()(pool22)
```

**Merge input models**

```
merge = concatenate([flat1, flat2])
# interpretation model
hidden1 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(merge)
hidden2 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(hidden1)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(hidden2)
model = Model(inputs=[visible1, visible2], outputs=output)
# summarize layers
print(model.summary())
```

**Model summary**

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to
====================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)             (None, 64, 64, 1)     0
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)             (None, 32, 32, 3)     0
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)                (None, 61, 61, 32)    544         input_1[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)                (None, 29, 29, 32)    1568        input_2[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 30, 30, 32)    0           conv2d_1[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 14, 14, 32)    0           conv2d_3[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)                (None, 27, 27, 16)    8208        max_pooling2d_1[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)                (None, 11, 11, 16)    8208        max_pooling2d_3[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 13, 13, 16)    0           conv2d_2[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 5, 5, 16)      0           conv2d_4[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)              (None, 2704)          0           max_pooling2d_2[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)              (None, 400)           0           max_pooling2d_4[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)      (None, 3104)          0           flatten_1[0][0]
                                                                   flatten_2[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                  (None, 10)            31050       concatenate_1[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                  (None, 10)            110         dense_1[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                  (None, 1)             11          dense_2[0][0]
====================================================================================================
Total params: 49,699
Trainable params: 49,699
Non-trainable params: 0
```

**Plot graph**

```
plot_model(model, to_file='multiple_inputs.png')
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this but it's a different model architecture in my opinion